# Build html tag using variable name for element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to use a string variable which could contain the values h1, h2, h3 etc to build some html. This works fine for the opening tag, but does not work nicely for the closing tag. If I write

```
@{ var tag = "h1" ; }
<@tag>some title here</@tag>
```

I end up with the html

```
<h1>some title here</@h1>
```

A work-around which seems to work is

```
<@tag>some title here<@("/"+tag)>
```

but it's pretty ugly. Is there some escape sequence I need to use here?

Comment: Would creating a custom HTML helper work? Something like `@Html.MyCustomTag("h1", "some title here")` using `TagBuilder`?

Comment: @PaulAbbott I'm sure that would be a perfectly good way to do it, but I was curious as to the syntax (or escape sequence) I needed to use in the problem above.

Comment: Works fine for me in both MVC4 and MVC5

Comment: It works in ASP.NET Core MVC too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Html.Raw.

```
string lineTemplate = "<h{0}>{1}</h{0}>";
for (int tagCounter = 1; tagCounter < 7; tagCounter++)
{
    @Html.Raw(string.Format(lineTemplate, tagCounter, "Header "+ tagCounter));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure which Razor version you are using

but i tested your code in my MVC4, it works perfectly

it will render `<h1>something</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

@Html.Raw($"<{tag}>some title here</{tag}>")